# Bitcoin Wallet Unsynched and Lost BTC?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I downloaded the original bitcoin wallet for the mac in 2014. I purchased my first BTC around that date and I simply did not keep my wallet synched and up to date. I attempted to download the blockchain from bitcointalk.org and it did not work. However, after downloading, my wallet now says I have 0.0 BTC available and 0.0BTC pending. However, on the right side you can still see the transaction history from when I originally bought the BTC and it shows the full amount there. Is my BTC permanently gone? How can I retrieve my BTC and synch my wallet to the current blockchain? Any help would be great and I would even be willing to send some BTC as a reward to anyone who can help me retrieve my BTC.

Comment: You are fully synced and now it says there are no funds? Did you switch or accidently move your wallet.dat file? If your client is fully synced, open up the console and type `listrecceivedbyaddress 0 true` and see if it responds with the address you are looking for.

Comment: From your question's text, it appears that your wallet is not synchronized yet. You may want to wait for synchronization to conclude and then see if your problem is solved. If it takes too long, you may want to consider upgrading to a newer version, as many improvements have been made to speed up the synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know your Bitcoin address?

Check on https://blockchain.info/ that it still has a value.

Locate `wallet.dat`, it should be in `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`.

Install MultiBit and get a new address.

Visit https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet. Drag the wallet.dat file into the dotted area. Follow the instructions.

Send your coins from blockchain.info to your new MultiBit address.

You'll now be in control of your coins again without requiring huge blockchain downloads.